# Set cookie in java, read in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, cookies

I'm trying something similar to this: [Detect when browser receives file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

I'm using Chromes Developer Tools to monitor my cookies and my problem is that the cookies I set in my server side code (java in my case) are only visible on the request. Not when I check the Resources tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

I think it might have something to do with the fact that my request is submitted by constructing a hidden form and submitting this (I'm using ExtJS 4.2.2).

All I can see in my Resources tab is the JSESSIONID cookie from Tomcat.

Can anyone help me set cookies from java that I can read in JavaScript after the request completes?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So are you basing this only off of the data a tool provides you, or did you in fact try to read the cookie using Javascript after the request completes and the cookie isn't there? Did you do a dump of the response that the server generates? What is in there?

Comment: Yes I tried reading the cookie and document.cookie only returns the JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: That leaves the "checking the response from the server" part of my questions.

Comment: Not quite sure what u mean @Gimby. See screenshots in updated question. Why can't I see downloadCookie006 using document.cookie?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this but heres one that would allow you to drop the cookie approach. You really should be setting your cookies to HttpOnly for security reasons unless you have a use case that requires it.

1. Expose your submit button in some sort of Iframe so users can submit
   the file while still remaining on the primary page.
2. Detect when a click occurs in the iFrame and start polling through
   AJAX at some URL such as "/FileUploadStatus".
3. On the server side once the file is completed upload set a session
   attribute such as

   `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   session.setAttribute("fileUploadStatus",true);`
4. When the AJAX request hits the servlet at `/FileUploadStatus`, check the session variable to see if the the file upload servlet has changed the value of  `fileUploadStatus` to true. If so then return an indication to the client to stop polling and update
   the page and clear the session attribute on the server.

**NOTE:** Detecting a click in an iFrame is hairy stuff across various browsers. You might have to just start polling the second they access your "Upload Page" and simply wait.

**Alternate Solution:** You could also form a direct connection using the new WebSocket API. THis approach runs the fastest but not all browsers support websockets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Usman. Unfortunately I'm restricted in terms of how creative I can be due to other solutions using the same code. I will try to make a sample solution and see how far your suggestion takes me. Thanks!